# Jenkins display multiple JMeter report(.jtl) in single graph

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, jenkins-plugins, performance-testing

In Jenkins, I have configured multiple JMeter scripts using maven-jmeter-plugin in single job. After execution, each JMeter script is generating its own report file(`.jtl`) in results folder.

I have also configured the Performance plugin of Jenkins to display the report after JMeter script execution.

My problem is, the Performance plugin is showing different graph for each `.jtl` file.
**Current Graph**

[image: Current Graph]

I need to report to be shown in single graph.
**Expected Graph**
[image: Expected Merged Graph]

Is there any plugin available to achieve the same?
if no, how can I update the current plugin to achieve merged graph?

Answer (score 2):

There is [Merge Results](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/) plugin which can be used for combining/comparing results of up to 4 different JMeter tests.

You can install the plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image]

Merge Results tool can also be used in command-line

1. Amend `merge-results.properties` (by default it's located in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation), make sure it contains these lines:

   ```
   inputJtl1=TestResult_1.jtl
   inputJtl2=TestResult_2.jtl
   ```
2. Execute Merge Results using [JMeter Plugins Command Line Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/) like:

   ```
    JMeterPluginsCMD --tool Reporter --generate-csv CombinedResult.jtl --input-jtl merge-results.properties --plugin-type MergeResults
   ```
3. Configure [Jenkins Performance Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Performance+Plugin) to read `CombinedResult.jtl` file instead of your 2 files.

Comment: Merging the JTL will not show multiple lines in single graph generated by Jenkins Performance Plugin - Trend Report? any solution on Jenkins side?